# redis usage for semantic web application RDF quads alongside SparQL

Tags: mysql, redis, datasource, semantic-web

I am the sysadmin supporting a Semantic Web application which runs on Tomcat and is using MySQL for the datastore. The dynamic nature of the queries cause the larger pages to be exponentially slower load times than pages with less dynamic content.  The database is queried with scan type Select statements millions of times a day, and it is my thinking that the SparQL generated queries are not the the most efficient, but changing them seems to be out of our hands as the queries are somewhat of a black box to the developers.  What I would like to know is, can Redis be used in a situation like this to handle the semantic relational data sets RDF (quads, triples, etc)?  I am not very knowledgeable on this, so an explanation/links would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, MySQL is not an acceptable backend for a triplestore.  You should consider using any one of the many dedicated triple stores, any of them will probably outperform MySQL because they do not have the impedance mismatch of triple to store triples/quads into a relational store; they're using native storage.

There is no production ready solution based on Redis that I'm aware of.  A quick google turned up a couple projects that seem to be related, but they may not meet your requirements.